# merge 2 csv files by columns error related to strings?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to merge 2 csv files by column.
my both csv ends with '_4.csv' as filename, and the final result of the merged csv is something like below:

```
    0-10       ,83.72,66.76,86.98  ,0-10       ,83.72,66.76,86.98
    11-20      ,15.01,31.12,12.04  ,11-20      ,15.01,31.12,12.04
    21-30      ,1.14,2.05,0.94     ,21-30      ,1.14,2.05,0.94
    31-40      ,0.13,0.07,0.03     ,31-40      ,0.13,0.07,0.03
    over 40    ,0.0,0.0,0.0        ,over 40    ,0.0,0.0,0.0
    UHF case   ,0.0,0.0,0.0        ,UHF case   ,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

my code:

```
    #combine 2 csv into 1 by columns
    files_in_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('_4.csv')]
    temp_data = []
    for filenames in files_in_dir:
        temp_data.append(np.loadtxt(filenames,dtype='str'))
    temp_data = np.array(temp_data)
    np.savetxt('_mix.csv',temp_data.transpose(),fmt='%s',delimiter=',')
```

however the error said:

```
    temp_data.append(np.loadtxt(filenames,dtype='str'))
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
    raise ValueError("Wrong number of columns at line %d"
    ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2
```

not sure if it is related to the first column being strings rather than values.
Does anyone know how to fix it? much appreciation

Comment: Do you have a common primary key to merge the two dataframes on?

Comment: I dont think so, I just want to merge 2 csv with all columns, I edit my question

Comment: I think my first answer was not quite right, I edited it substantially and included the data in the question. Let me know if this is closer to what the question intended.

Comment: @chenabien, If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) method. If we have two `.csv` files of the form:

```
0-10       ,83.72,66.76,86.98
11-20      ,15.01,31.12,12.04
21-30      ,1.14,2.05,0.94
31-40      ,0.13,0.07,0.03
over 40    ,0.0,0.0,0.0
UHF case   ,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

Assuming they both have similar structure, we'll work with one of these named `data.csv`:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Assumes there are no headers
df1 = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)

# By default: DataFrame headers are assigned numbers 0, 1, 2, 3
# In the second data frame, we will rename columns so they do not clash.
#   meaning `df2` will now have columns named: 4, 5, 6, 7
df2 = df2.rename(
    columns={
        x: y for x, y in zip(df1.columns, range(len(df2.columns), len(df2.columns) * 2))
    }
)

print(df1.join(df2))
```

Example output:

```
             0      1      2      3            4      5      6      7
0  0-10         83.72  66.76  86.98  0-10         83.72  66.76  86.98
1  11-20        15.01  31.12  12.04  11-20        15.01  31.12  12.04
2  21-30         1.14   2.05   0.94  21-30         1.14   2.05   0.94
3  31-40         0.13   0.07   0.03  31-40         0.13   0.07   0.03
4  over 40       0.00   0.00   0.00  over 40       0.00   0.00   0.00
5  UHF case      0.00   0.00   0.00  UHF case      0.00   0.00   0.00
```